# Group by time interval for 24 hrs and assign group values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a pandas data frame like below that contains date-time values in column `B`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['XYZ', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'XYZ', 'PQR', 'PQR', 'PQR', 'PQR', 'CVB', 'CVB', 'CVB', 'CVB'], 
        'B': ['2022-02-16 14:00:31', '2022-02-16 16:11:26', '2022-02-16 17:31:26', '2022-02-16 22:47:46', '2022-02-17 07:11:11', '2022-02-17 10:43:36', '2022-02-17 15:05:11', '2022-02-18 18:06:12', '2022-02-19 09:05:46', '2022-02-19 13:02:16', '2022-02-19 18:05:26', '2022-02-19 22:05:26']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])
df


     |   A   |          B           |                                 
     +-------+----------------------+
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 14:00:31 |                  
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 16:11:26 |         
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 17:31:26 | 
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 22:47:46 |  
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 07:11:11 | 
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 10:43:36 |
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 15:05:11 |
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-18 18:06:12 |
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 09:05:46 |
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 13:02:16 |
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 18:05:26 |
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 22:05:26 |
     +-------+----------------------+
```

I want to group the date-time values for 24hr interval period, such that my output should look like below.

```
Expected Output :

     |   A   |          B           |   Group  |                               
     +-------+----------------------+-----------
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 14:00:31 |     1    |        
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 16:11:26 |     1    |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 17:31:26 |     1    |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 22:47:46 |     1    |
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 07:11:11 |     1    |  
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 10:43:36 |     1    |     
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 15:05:11 |     2    |  
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-18 18:06:12 |     3    |  
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 09:05:46 |     3    | 
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 13:02:16 |     3    |
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 18:05:26 |     3    |
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 22:05:26 |     4    |
     +-------+----------------------+----------+
```

Currently, I tried to group the date-time values in column `B` for the 24hr interval time period using the below code, which resulted in an unsuccessful output that I'm not expecting. My 24hr period will first start from the initial datetime i.e `2022-02-16 14:00:31` and then the next 24hr period will start from `2022-02-17 15:05:11` and so on.

```
df1 = df.reset_index().set_index(df['B']).rename_axis(None)
df1.loc[df1.first('24h').index, "GROUP"] = 1
df1

Actual Output :

     |   A   |          B           |   Group    |                               
     +-------+----------------------+------------+
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 14:00:31 |     1      |        
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 16:11:26 |     1      |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 17:31:26 |     1      |
     |  XYZ  |  2022-02-16 22:47:46 |     1      |
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 07:11:11 |     1      |  
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 10:43:36 |     1      |     
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-17 15:05:11 |     NaN    |  
     |  PQR  |  2022-02-18 18:06:12 |     NaN    |  
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 09:05:46 |     NaN    | 
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 13:02:16 |     NaN    |
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 18:05:26 |     NaN    |
     |  CVB  |  2022-02-19 22:05:26 |     NaN    |
     +-------+----------------------+------------+
```

Is there a way where I can group the date-time values for the 24hr time interval period such that I can get the expected output as shown? I want to have an efficient solution so that the code can run on 1 million time stamps efficiently.

Comment: How do you define your 24 hour periods.  Does the first start at `2022-02-16 14:00:31`?  Are they contiguous or is there gaps between them, i.e. Does the second period start at start of first period + 24hrs, or does it start at `2022-02-17 15:05:11`?

Comment: @Riley : My 24 hour periods start first from the `2022-02-16 14:00:31`. The second period starts + 24 hrs from the first period (`2022-02-16 14:00:31`) which in my case will be `2022-02-17 15:05:11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as each step of this process depends on the result of the previous one, we can't use `resample` and `transform`. We have to iterate all the data sequentially mapping them in a prescribed manner:

```
step = pd.Timedelta('24H')
sentinel = df.loc[0, 'B'] + step
group_id = 1
for index, value in df['B'].items():
    if value > sentinel:
        sentinel = value + step
        group_id += 1
    df.loc[index, 'Group'] = group_id
```

We can also hide this process in a `Series.map` with help of a generator, which may work somewhat faster:

```
def gen(start, step):
    sentinel = start + step
    group_id = 1
    value = yield
    while True:
        if value > sentinel:
            sentinel = value + step
            group_id += 1
        value = yield group_id


start, step = df.loc[0, 'B'], pd.Timedelta('24H')
marker = gen(start, step).send
marker(None)     # pump/init/push the generator to the first yield
df['Group'] = df['B'].map(marker)
del marker
```

Note, that all this works if `df['B']` is sorted beforehand (which seems logical to assume due to the described grouping algorithm).

**Update (about generators)**

A new generator `gen(start, step)` has a methond `.send(...)` used to pass inside of it some value. So we can switch from the generator itself to the function `my_func = get(start, step).send` which will get some value and return next item from the original generator depending on this value (saving its internal state between calls).

The first call `my_func(None)` is initialisation of the generator (pushing the code up to the first `yield`). Next time, when we call `my_func(val)` the variable `val` will be passed inside the generator (it will be assigned to `value` in the code above at the 4th line `value = yield`), and the code of the generator will continue processing from the next line after `yield` until it reaches next yielding, and so on.

As for the line `del marker`, it is the manual deletion of a variable that refers to a generator object. Nothing special, just cleaning (not sure if it's vital though, we can delete this line).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, can the code be used for other time intervals say like `10mins` or `15mins` or `30days` apart from `24H` window interval ?

Comment: @user3046211 I think yes. We have to specify the right `step` (the time delta interval to look forward from a starting point). For example, it may be assigned to  `pd.Timedelta(10, 'minutes')`, `pd.Timedelta('0.25H')`, `pd.Timedelta('30D')` or `pd.Timedelta('1 day 10:45:00')`, which are 10 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 days and 1 day 10 hours 45 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I set `pd.Timedelta('10min')` for 10 mins. Another Quick question : What does `marker(None)` mean in the code ? Can it be commented out in the code along with `del marker` ?

Comment: very comprehensive answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

edit: More efficient solution:

```
df['day'] = df['B'].dt.day
df['group_id'] = df.groupby('day').ngroup() + 1
```

it was a bit of a long solution I'm sure there are more efficient solutions but you can use this:

```
df['day']=df['B'].dt.day
df2=df.groupby(df['B'].dt.day).agg(count_col=('B', 'count')).sort_index().reset_index().reset_index().drop(['count_col'],axis=1).rename(columns={'index':'group_id','B':'day'})
df=df.merge(df2,how='left',on='day').drop(['day'],axis=1)
print(df)
'''
    A   B                   group_id
0   XYZ 2022-02-16 14:00:31 0
1   XYZ 2022-02-16 16:11:26 0
2   XYZ 2022-02-16 17:31:26 0
3   XYZ 2022-02-16 22:47:46 0
4   PQR 2022-02-17 07:11:11 1
5   PQR 2022-02-17 10:43:36 1
6   PQR 2022-02-17 15:05:11 1
7   PQR 2022-02-18 18:06:12 2
8   CVB 2022-02-19 09:05:46 3
9   CVB 2022-02-19 13:02:16 3
10  CVB 2022-02-19 18:05:26 3
11  CVB 2022-02-19 22:05:26 3
'''
```

If you want the group_id value to start at 1:

```
df['day']=df['B'].dt.day
df.index=df.index +1 
df2=df.groupby(df['B'].dt.day).agg(count_col=('B', 'count')).sort_index().reset_index()
df2.index=df2.index +1
df2=df2.reset_index().drop(['count_col'],axis=1).rename(columns={'index':'group_id','B':'day'})
df=df.merge(df2,how='left',left_on='day',right_on='day').drop(['day'],axis=1)
print(df)
'''
    A   B                   group_id
0   XYZ 2022-02-16 14:00:31 1
1   XYZ 2022-02-16 16:11:26 1
2   XYZ 2022-02-16 17:31:26 1
3   XYZ 2022-02-16 22:47:46 1
4   PQR 2022-02-17 07:11:11 2
5   PQR 2022-02-17 10:43:36 2
6   PQR 2022-02-17 15:05:11 2
7   PQR 2022-02-18 18:06:12 3
8   CVB 2022-02-19 09:05:46 4
9   CVB 2022-02-19 13:02:16 4
10  CVB 2022-02-19 18:05:26 4
11  CVB 2022-02-19 22:05:26 4

'''
```